# How does TensorFlow generate gen_array_ops.py via array_ops.cc?

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow generates code automatically. I am curious about how TF generates `gen_array_ops.py` by [`array_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/array_ops.cc) ?

The generated python file is at `python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py`

```
"""Python wrappers around TensorFlow ops.

This file is MACHINE GENERATED! Do not edit.
Original C++ source file: array_ops.cc
"""
...
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Python code generation is done at building time through Bazel. You can find the relevant definition in [`tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L795-L919), I will post here just the header:

```
# Generates a Python library target wrapping the ops registered in "deps".
#
# Args:
#   name: used as the name of the generated target and as a name component of
#     the intermediate files.
#   out: name of the python file created by this rule. If None, then
#     "ops/gen_{name}.py" is used.
#   hidden: Optional list of ops names to make private in the Python module.
#     It is invalid to specify both "hidden" and "op_whitelist".
#   visibility: passed to py_library.
#   deps: list of dependencies for the intermediate tool used to generate the
#     python target. NOTE these `deps` are not applied to the final python
#     library target itself.
#   require_shape_functions: leave this as False.
#   hidden_file: optional file that contains a list of op names to make private
#     in the generated Python module. Each op name should be on a line by
#     itself. Lines that start with characters that are invalid op name
#     starting characters are treated as comments and ignored.
#   generated_target_name: name of the generated target (overrides the
#     "name" arg)
#   op_whitelist: if not empty, only op names in this list will be wrapped. It
#     is invalid to specify both "hidden" and "op_whitelist".
#   cc_linkopts: Optional linkopts to be added to tf_cc_binary that contains the
#     specified ops.

def tf_gen_op_wrapper_py(
        name,
        out = None,
        hidden = None,
        visibility = None,
        deps = [],
        require_shape_functions = False,
        hidden_file = None,
        generated_target_name = None,
        op_whitelist = [],
        cc_linkopts = [],
        api_def_srcs = []):
    # ...
```

This is called indirectly through `tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py` which you can find in [`tensorflow/python/build_defs.bzl`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/build_defs.bzl). For the case of `array_ops`, you will find it in [`tensorflow/python/BUILD`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/BUILD#L1843-L1851):

```
tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(
    name = "array_ops_gen",
    visibility = [
        "//learning/brain/python/ops:__pkg__",
        "//tensorflow/compiler/tests:__pkg__",
        "//tensorflow/contrib/quantization:__pkg__",
        "//tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:__pkg__",
    ],
)
```

And what does this rule do? It calls a program which source you can find at [`tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen_main.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen_main.cc) (that is the main entry point, it uses other neighboring source files). Essentially, it is a program that goes through the ops registered through the `REGISTER_OP` macro (defined in [`tensorflow/core/framework/op.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h)) and produces Python code accordingly. I cannot go through the specifics now but you should be able to browse the code if you want to know the details.